# Does all wifi traffic go through the router?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point, wifi-configuration

Say I have two laptops connected to a wireless network through a standard wireless AP/router. The laptops are both right next to each other,but the router is far away. If laptopA sends some ip packets addressed to laptopB, do all of those packets end up going through the router or will laptopB see an arp request or something and they'll be able to bypass the router and exchange data directly like they're on a hub?

Basically, does it matter how physically close two nodes are or just how close they are to the AP?

Comment: *ad hoc* connections are point to point. Any other will go through the AP.

Comment: For questions like this, you need to distinguish between the _router_ part (which is bypassed) and the _WiFi AP_ part (which isn't).

Comment: Can you explain that statement a little, grawity? The traffic could go through the AP, but not get routed?

Comment: I think what gravity means is that the router us acting like both a router (or push traffic between LAN and wan ports) and  switch/ap functionality.  The router part - or forwarding packets using through the CPU is not required for this functionality - however the packet is still handled by the switch/ap part of the router which theoretically does not require the CPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost always the connections will traverse the AP, but this does actually depend on your particular hardware.

If the devices support and are configured to use WIFI Direct/P2P-Go then they can talk to each other without going through a route.  There is also 802.11s to set up a mesh network.

Answer (score 2):

All traffic between clients of an access point will go through the access point.